# Recoding printf; error in .h file: compiler doesn't recognise the va_list type

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

I'm recoding `printf` in C. So i'm calling functions for each types of variables, so i prototyped all of them in a .h. But i got this error:

```
main.h:22:13: error: unknown type name ‘va_list’
     int dispdi(va_list ap);
```

Solutions?

Comment: Did you `#include <stdarg.h>` ?

Comment: Since you refer to va_list in the .h file, it'd probably be a good idea to define that type (by including stdarg.h) in it first.

Comment: where ever you are using variadic functions, visibility to the definitions of va_list, va_start, va_arg et. al. have to be visible.  The suggestion to #include <stdarg.h> is accurate (depending on your environment)  You can include it in either a .h or a .c, depending on where it will provide visibility to your variadic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If*** you are creating all of your own definitions, including va_list, then 
I assume the definition(s) you created in your .h looked *at least similar* to:

```
#ifndef _VA_LIST_DEFINED
#ifdef _M_CEE_PURE
typedef System::ArgIterator va_list;
#else
typedef char *  va_list;
#endif
#define _VA_LIST_DEFINED
#endif
```

Just include this .h where ever you are using your version of printf

***However, if*** you are using the standard C defines for va_list, va_start, va_arg et. al., then simply include stdarg.h.

***In either case***, here is an example of a simple variadic function (not printf, just a simple example) using the va_ macros:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void variadic_function(int Param, ...) 
{
    int dslot;
    va_list params;
    va_start(params, Param);
    dslot = va_arg(params, int);
    va_end(args);
}
```

***For further reading***, [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h) and its links round out the topic well.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the `stdarg.h` header file before using `va_list` and friends.

You header file may be something like:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
...
int my_printf (const char *format, ...);
...
```